# PHP: Reuse Open MySQL Connection from mysql_connect() PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am just curious to see if there is a way to transfer or re-use a connection opened by `mysql_connect()` to PDO.
I know this is incorrect (hoping to get the sort of idea across), but i was hoping for something like

```
$pdo = new PDO($mysql_connect_link); // yes this is wrong, i know!
```

for example.

The reason is that I want to use `PDO` in my class to manage queries and such, however, the class itself doesn't open the connection to the database. It requires a connection to be established beforehand (which I have been checking via the standard `mysql_*`() function set for now. Ew, I know.)

I would like for the class's queries to work regardless on the user opening a connection to the database via `mysql_*` *or* `PDO`... Does anyone have any thoughts and/or suggestions on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just curious to see if there is a way to transfer a connection opened by mysql_connect() to PDO.

**NO**

> I would like for the class's queries to work regardless on the user opening a connection to the database via mysql_* or PDO...

It's quite hard to understand your reasons.

If you want to keep both drivers, you have to keep 2 sets of functions as well. And completely change the class structure. You have to have an abstract class with common methods and 2 implementations for them. No connections passed to the class but class itself have to manage connection. I doubt it worth such a labor though.

If you just want to allow use of your class along with some legacy mysql_* code - just open another connection from PDO. It's not such an evil thing to be avoided at any cost. It's just a connection.  It will burden your server slightly, yes, but it will be least problem for the application that uses such a sandwiched spaghetti.

Comment: I'll just make an installer package. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

You should just port your mysql_ functions to PDO.

```
$pdo = new PDO($mysql_connect_link);
```

Is wrong because of the parameters it takes (see: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.construct.php), but yes technically you could have both connections running side by side. Although, no, you obviously can't run PDO queries with a run of the mill mysql_connect.